# PHP turn PM and AM into 24 hour

Tags: php, date, time

So I need away to in PHP turn pm / am into 24 hour time, We use Yahoo API to get currency rates, but they seem to give it to us by am/pm.

I thought date might work, but when I read into that function it would had no way to turning pm into 24 hours.

```
5: 55pm
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work

```
date("H:i", strtotime("5:55 pm"));
```

and if you want to go the other way,

```
date("g:i a", strtotime("17:55"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Yahoo! API really does not provide a way to return the time in 24 hours, you could do as sachleen suggested, or use a regex.

```
(\d{1,2}): (\d{2})(am|pm)
```

Then just add 12 to the hours if it's "pm".

Answer (score 0):

problem with using `date` and `strtotime` is you may have to worry about timezone... what you are getting from yahoo may not line up with your server's timezone...here is a regex method:

```
$time = preg_replace_callback('~^([^:]+)(.*(a|p)m)$~',create_function('$m','return ($m[3]=="p")?(($m[1]+12).$m[2]):$m[0];'),$time);
```

Comment: strtotime and date should be safe unless the timezone changes between the call to strtotime and date.