# php turning number (hours) to php date and time format

Tags: php, date

If I have hours in the following format :
2:30 am how can I turn it into :
14:30:00

and if I got the date 2013-07-17 and the time 14:30:00 how can I turn it to a datatimestamp ?
for example this will produce : 1374053400

thanks.

Comment: This question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905959/php-turn-pm-and-am-into-24-hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

am is before noon, not after..

This is what I would do:

```
$timeString = '2:30 am';
$dateString = '2013-07-17';
$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$date = new DateTime($dateString . ' ' . $timeString, $timeZone);

echo $date->format('H:i:s'); // 02:30:00
echo $date->getTimestamp(); // the timestamp as int
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to search in this site? :)

The second question has a really-similar one here:
[How to convert date to timestamp in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/how-to-convert-date-to-timestamp-in-php)

As for the first one, the answer is in the official php documentation:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks, I have searched and I havent found, I must searched the wrong thing.